# How to turn off third party app store and side loading except my app store

Tags: api, android-development, settings

I want to prevent installing apps using third party app stores but except only one app store. This specific app store is in my control. I can change it's code to send a message to the mobile device that this store is special.

I can disable `Unknown sources` setting in `security` settings using android API according to  [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026554/turn-on-unknown-sources-setting-programatically). But if I do that, All the third party app stores will be blocked including my app store.

Any Idea to achieve this requirement using android API would be much appreciated.

Comment: The linked to answer suggests you cannot even change the setting to only the official store ("You cannot hold that permission, unless you are signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware or if you were installed on the system partition"). And more importantly; why would your users want your to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to create malware that prevents Android phones from ever being able to install apps from sources other than you. What other use could this possibly have? Do Android users normally see unwanted app stores spontaneously appearing on their phones? If an API did exist to do this, wouldn't it be a tremendous security failure?